# Print Indian rupee symbol using OVIO Bluetooth thermal printer

Tags: printing, printer, android, bluetooth

I am using an OVIO Bluetooth thermal printer. I want to print the Indian Rupee symbol (**₹**). When i append the symbol to string and send the string to be printed, everything is printed fine other than the symbol. A "**?**" symbol is printed instead of "**₹**". I have set charset encoding to `UTF-8`.

You can find the printer manual from [THIS LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f1rLebJH3tmsV-9jALLRUs5kyIXZFRGC/view?usp=sharing). In the manual, on **Page 11**, there is an option to define user-defined character but don't know how that can be achieved.

Comment: The printer manual doesn't say anything about Unicode support. Instead, it mentions old-school PC "code pages", and it has a very short list of supported code pages, none of which sound like any kind of south asian / indian subcontinent scripts. So I think it simply doesn't contain the symbol you want to print. I think you're out of luck unless you can find a way to feed the printer custom graphics or put it in raster mode or something.

Comment: So I guess I'm confirming that you are going to have to do what you said in your last sentence: create a user-defined character and tell it to print that.

Comment: But then I don't know how that can be achieved. By the way, thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @Spiff: please make that comment into an answer.